# Creating a flag for rows with missing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want to create a new column.

- This new column would return 1 if all columns in the row have a value (are not Nan)
- If there was a Nan in any one of the columns in the row it would return 0

Does anyone have guidance on how to go about this?

I have used the below to sum the instances of 'Not Nans' in the row, which could possibly be used in an if statement? or is there a more simple way

```
code_count.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
code_count['count_languages'] = code_count.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) for test non missing values with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all values per rows are `True`, then convert mask to `1,0` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
code_count['count_languages'] = code_count.notna().all(axis=1).view('i1')
```

Or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
code_count['count_languages'] = code_count.notna().all(axis=1).astype('int')
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
code_count['count_languages'] = np.where(code_count.notna().all(axis=1), 1, 0)
```